# Geolocations - How to check if 2 circles are overlapping

Tags: algorithm, geolocation, gis

Let's say we have 2 locations (latitude,longitude) and each location has a radius (it may be different from each other), making a circle. How to check if these 2 circles are overlapping?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check if the distance between the centers is smaller than the sum of the radii.

Say for circles *A* and *B* with radius *A<sub>r</sub>* and *B<sub>r</sub>* respectively, and coordinates (*A<sub>x</sub>*, *A<sub>y</sub>*) and (*B<sub>x</sub>*, *B<sub>y</sub>*) respectively, the distance between the circles is

*D = sqrt( (A<sub>x</sub> - B<sub>x</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (A<sub>y</sub> - B<sub>y</sub>)<sup>2</sup> )*

They overlap when

*D < A<sub>r</sub> + B<sub>r</sub>*

There's a catch, however: the centers of the circles are placed on a sphere. The shortest distance between them is a straight line, beneath the sphere's surface. The distance between them following the surface will be larger. For instance, the distance between the North and South pole is 2 Earth radii, but the path on the surface will be *2π* Earth radii. Also, these circles don't overlap. So, the above equations only hold when the distances are relatively small.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: You're welcome - I updated the question with a caveat. If you're using an API or database or library there's probably built-in functionality to calculate the distance accurately.

Comment: Regarding your last edit, there is no problem because the distances will be <100m